# css printing exact size

Tags: html, css, printing

UPD1. 
I have two printers:

- a printer, thar prints stickers (EAN13 barcodes)`44mm` x `23mm`
- a default LaserJet printer (size A4)

I have two web-pages.

First page have a `DIV` with dimensions `44mm` x `23mm` setted in `css`:

```
@page {
    size: 40mm 23mm;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If I click in browser `Print Preview` I'd like to see only one page with exact width and height (44mm x 23 mm)

Second page have a `DIV` that have lot of data. It have to be restricted by width to `A4` width, but may have multiple pages. If I click in browser `Print Preview` I wanna see A4-sized preview.

What browsers support this? `Firefox 7` and `Chrome 16.0.912` doesnt.
Is it possible to print exactly what I want with exactly size I want in HTML5/CSS/etc...

Comment: What is the current behaviour? What do you mean by "This code doesn't work"?

Comment: I get 19 blank pages in Chrome Print Preview dialog :), so I don't know why `19` pages? and why they are blank. I need only one page with exact width and height.

Comment: Why is the body set to visibility:hidden?

Comment: for `screen` other css, for `print` another

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you included the jQuery Extension for barcode?

Comment: Of course yes. I see barcode on screen :) And do you have exactly one page in print preview? Can you share own code?

Answer (score 2):

I just gathered pieces from all over and put it altogether. It is working for me:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://barcode-coder.com/js/jquery-barcode-last.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#ean").barcode("9785903979165", "ean13", {barWidth:2});
    });
</script>
<style>
#ean {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40mm;
    height: 23mm;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ean">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it does not work. If I change `width` and `height` or setup `@page size` values - in print preview browser windows sizes doesn't change.

Comment: perfect solution for me , but how can i print more than page with the diffrent bar code numbers